# Loading binary data resources (just like images, audio, etc) in javascript?

Tags: javascript, resources, binary-data

I can load remote resources such as images, audio, etc like this:

```js
var picture = new Image();
picture.src = 'https://example.com/something.jpg';

var sound = new Audio();
sound.src = 'https://example.com/music.mp3';
```

Is there also a way to do this for binary data? i.e. like:

```js
var data = new DataObject();
data.src = 'https://example.com/binary.dat';
```

Is there something like the imaginary `DataObject` in the above example, or can I set it up like that somehow?

Comment: you can use ajax... for example `var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', '/binary.dat', true);
  xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
  xhr.onload = function (e) {
                   console.log('data', this.response);
  };
  xhr.send();`

Comment: Yeah I know about ajax but that only allows me to load resources from my own domain. I would like to load *remote* resources (binary data), for example from CDNs. Just like I can load remote image and sound resources.

Comment: What do you mean with "load" access the bytes?

Comment: @RolandStarke Yes, just access the raw data. For example getting the bytes in an UInt8Array or something.

Comment: You can't do that cross origin i fear.

Comment: @RolandStarke But JS can read image and audio resources cross origin (see examples above). Which basically boils down to javascript reading remote files and interpreting them as images or audio. Is there not a similar object or method to read "random" (i.e. binary) data, which does the same except for the interpreting as images or audio?

Comment: Well the above example (but with a valid image URL of course) will load the image data in memory just fine, without displaying anything or 'doing' anything with the image. Note that the `picture` in my example above is just an object in code, not a DOM element or part of my webpage or anything. I can process the image in-memory however I want. The only thing is I cannot access the actual raw bytes in the JPG file, only the image contents (pixels/colors).

Comment: @RolandStarke That's just a matter of overriding the crossorigin in code: https://jsfiddle.net/0pn9yLc6/

Comment: Interesting. But seems it only works if `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` is set.

Comment: @RolandStarke On the remote end, you mean? Sure yes, but it's OK if I can only access binary files (or image data in this case) from servers that allow it.

Comment: Yes on the image in this case (the fiddle). So, the binary data you want to access has `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`? Then i suggest ajax: https://jsfiddle.net/8guhzdtp/

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) with 'application/octet-stream' type

Comment: Thanks but aren't Blobs only for **generating** binary data objects, and them allowing them to save local i.e. offer as a download to the visitor?

Comment: It creates file-like object with url and you can manage it as file from your server

Comment: Not sure if I understand you correctly. Can I somehow create a `Blob` and load its contents from `https://some.remote.location/data.bin` and then access the data in my code?

Comment: It can`t get around CORS if that is your question

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at this: developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Streams_API I believe it is what you're searching for.

> With Streams being available to JavaScript, this all changes — you can now start processing raw data with JavaScript bit by bit as soon as it is available on the client-side, without needing to generate a buffer, string, or blob.